# Where is log file from rc.local?

Tags: boot, log

I have some commands to in my rc.local. I know that they are failing. How can I get log file with messages produced by executing rc.local? Where is it located?

I have checked the /var/log/boot.log. I know my messages are not there because I know already what is the reason of failure. But I still want to make sure from log file.

Note, I don't want to run script again, I could but I don't want. I would rather analyse wht happened during startup.

Thanks for any help.

Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (if it matters)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Unless a command has output or logging already configured, `rc.local` commands will not log anywhere.

If you want to see logs for specific commands, try [redirecting the stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot) for `rc.local` to somewhere you can check. Try adding this to the top of your `/etc/rc.local` file:

```sh
exec 1>/tmp/rc.local.log 2>&1  # send stdout and stderr from rc.local to a log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution
```

Though this will require to rerun the `rc.local` file.

Comment: `exec &> /tmp/rc.local.log` is enough instead of the two exec calls :-)

Comment: @abu-bua: Please be careful when you review edit suggestions that introduce functional changes! `&>` redirection is a Bash-ism and fails silently in Dash and other “plain” implementations of `/bin/sh` interpreters like the one used for `rc.local`.

Comment: does "to the top" mean before the first line `!/bin/sh -e`?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10, `rc.local` seems to be configured to log in `/var/log/syslog`. For that OS, see other answers for less intrusive ways to access `rc.local` output.

Answer (score 19):

Try to check for failures in the `/var/log/syslog` file instead.

Comment: There are many lines so you can grep for `rc.local` for example like this: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep rc.local`

Answer (score 17):

With systemd rc.local is considered a service fo which systemd collects logs. You can review them with:

```
systemctl status rc.local.service
```

You can see errors (if they exist) through service log.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10, this is `systemctl status rc-local.service`.

Comment: Great answer!  Works on Raspian, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Look in

1. `/var/log/messages`
2. `/var/log/daemon`

Or use dmesg command

```
less /var/log/boot.log
less /var/log/dmesg
grep error /var/log/dmesg
grep <your expected error string> /var/log/boot.log
```

Or use `script` or some other tool to capture a log in `rc.local`

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Sylvain's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434242/where-is-log-file-from-rc-local/434249#434249):

`grep rc.local /var/log/syslog`

Will show you all error output related to `rc.local`

Comment: This is the correct answer.