# Logs of files added as startup application

Tags: scripts, startup, logs

I wrote a python script and added it to the list of startup applications in Ubuntu. After restarting the device I can find that the script has not run and I don't know where to find the logs. What is the default location in which the logs will be stored?

I searched around similar questions [such as this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434242/where-is-log-file-from-rc-local)I don't think this will apply for me as I am using a different method than the one mentioned in the question.

EDIT :
I did not add my script in rc.local or as a cron job. In ubuntu dash if you type startup you will get a window asking you to add commands that you want to execute on startup. I added my script in that window.

Comment: How do you autostart your script - using `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/ini.d/script_name`?

Comment: @M.Dm. In ubuntu dash if you type startup you will get a window asking you to add commands that you want to execute on startup. I added my script in that window.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: What *exact* command did you add to the list of start-up applications? How *exactly* did you verify that the program didn't run? There is no log file location for applications that aren't set up to generate them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added `python3 ...\main.py` to the list and if the program ran it is supposed to show a notification but I didn't get any. You can see my code here.https://github.com/RajNirmal/Python_Remainder/blob/master/main.py. I added a couple of `print()` lines in there but haven't updated the repo yet. The output of the `print()` function should be stored somewhere right?

Comment: Please verify that the *absolute* path to the Python program exists, e. g. with `ls -l ...\main.py`. Did you really use backslashes (`\ `) as path component delimiter? Linux and other Unix-like operating systems use forward slashes (`/`) for that. Again, please **[edit]** your post to add additional information so that future readers don't have to scour the comment section for it.

Answer (score 2):

After you added your python script to startup applications, a new '.desktop' file - corresponding to your script - have appeared in `~/.config/autostart`
That file contains a line saying:
`Exec=your_script.py`

A simple workaround would be to change in the .desktop file `your_script.py` to `wrapper.sh`, where `wrapper.sh` would be a new script simply reading:
`python your_script.py > your_log.txt`

Then, obviously, the output of `your_script.py` will appear in `your_log.txt`.

P.S. I would have added this workaround as a comment rather, than a solution, which I cannot do as a newly registered user. Sorry about that, hope it helps.